# Run sudo command within directory

Tags: bash, sudo, cd-command

Possible solutions could be:

1. Starting interactive session.

   ```
   sudo -s <<< "cd dir ; command"
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo /bin/bash -c "cd dir ; command"
   ```

   But I don't have /bin/bash /bin/sh /bin/su or other sudoer permissions
2. Changing directory before sudo is done.

   ```
   cd dir ; sudo command
   ```

   But I don't have permission to enter the dir.
3. I need a general case pwd set (like Popen cwd), so below is not answer I can use:

   ```
   sudo command /path/to/file
   ```

What I'm trying to write is python Popen wrapper with sudo=True/False option, and currently I'm trying to somehow get cwd parameter to work.

Comment: so run `sudo cd && sudo command`.

Comment: sudo: cd: command not found. sudo -i cd /root doesn't work as well

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place? Can't you run `command` on something in the directory? E.g. if `command` were `grep regex file`, just run `sudo grep regex dir/file`. Please provide more information in your question on the bigger picture here. And please [edit] your question for that rather than posting comments. :-)

Comment: Whenever i need to run a command in a `root` directory, I use `command /path/to/dir`

Comment: Ah, your edit you mention you're doing some coding in Python. Please share a minimal working example so we can help you better. :-)

Comment: `sudo` is used for running executables; `cd` is a **shell builtin**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what the bigger picture is, but your approach should be to run the command with *on* a file in the directory. E.g. if you want to run `grep regex file` where `file` is in `/root`, then you should approach it like this:

```
$ sudo grep regex /root/file
```

And *not*:

```
$ sudo 'cd /root; grep regex file'
sudo: cd /root; grep regex file: command not found
```

Why this output? Well, it's shell syntax and sudo isn't running the command in another interactive shell.

Another approach would be to alter the environment variable `PWD`, like this:

```
$ sudo -i PWD=/root grep regex file
```

Comment: The first approach I cannot use to set pwd in general case. (Added the bigger picture to the question) The second doesnt work for me since, it is not configured as you said (in general case for the user of our software)

Comment: @AndrewOnischuk yes, second approach doesn't work, you're right. removed it.

Comment: That actually works with -i specified sudo -i PWD=/root ls, thanks. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: A practical use case is when you need to run "make install" in a directory you don't own, e.g., in the home directory of an unprivileged user.  (The alternative in that case would be to use `sudo make -C ~unprivileged/project install`.)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109570/37428

Answer (score 2):

For me a combination of `sudo` and `screen` worked out:

```
sudo -iu vagrant screen -mS npm_install bash -c 'cd /vagrant && npm install'
```

This command first switches to the `vagrant` user. Then as `vagrant` changes the directory to `/vagrant` and executes `npm install`.